# "searchd" is showing "FATAL: bind() failed on 0.0.0.0: Address already in use"

Tags: linux, port, bind, sphinx

When I try the command `searchd`, it shows:

```
using config file '/usr/local/etc/sphinx.conf'...
WARNING: compat_sphinxql_magics=1 is deprecated; please update your application and config
listening on all interfaces, port=9312
bind() failed on 0.0.0.0, retrying...
bind() failed on 0.0.0.0, retrying...
bind() failed on 0.0.0.0, retrying...
bind() failed on 0.0.0.0, retrying...
bind() failed on 0.0.0.0, retrying...
bind() failed on 0.0.0.0, retrying...
bind() failed on 0.0.0.0, retrying...
bind() failed on 0.0.0.0, retrying...
bind() failed on 0.0.0.0, retrying...
bind() failed on 0.0.0.0, retrying...
bind() failed on 0.0.0.0, retrying...
bind() failed on 0.0.0.0, retrying...
FATAL: bind() failed on 0.0.0.0: Address already in use
```

and when I `netstat -nlp`, there already is `searchd` at that port.

- Conflict?
- What should I do?

Comment: Are you a `searchd` developer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> and when i ~# netstat -nlp, there already is "searchd" at that port.

So if you already have searchd running, why are you trying to start another one?

If you really do want to run two instances (why?), then you should arrange for them to be on different ports - each instance will need a seperate config file.

Comment: Ya, you are right. But for me, i just installed "Sphinx" manually myself right now. But there is an instance already running. So i'm getting complicated. Should i remove that instance or what.

Comment: maybe just try "searchd --stop" to stop the running instance. Failing that try "killall searchd" to kill all instances. Then try a normal startup. This assumes you are only aiming for one instance, and existing instance is just a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

May be you don't have privilege or direct access to address `0.0.0.0:9312` or it is already used by another process.

Try to change sphinx `searchd` configuration `listen` option to another address or make sure that address is available.